# cannot run my application on dart 1.6 release-stable and dart 1.7.0.dev_00_01

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

My application was being developed with 1.6.0-dev.09_07 and starting my application was done with no issue.

I switched to the 1.6.0.release-stable received the following error:

```
--- 8:03:25 AM Starting pub serve : epimss_design ---
Loading source assets...
Loading polymer/src/build/mirrors_remover, observe and smoke/src/default_transformer transformers...
'Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: SocketException: OS Error: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
, errno = 121, address = localhost, port = 58876
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:820)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:126)'
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 256                                                                                 Isolate.spawnUri
e:%5Cb%5Cbuild%5Cslave%5Cdart-editor-win-stable%5Cbuild%5Cdart%5Csdk%5Clib%5C_internal%5Cpub%5Clib%5Csrc%5Cdart.dart 179  _isolateBuffer
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 219                                                                                 _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 122                                                                                 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

I tried the 1.7.0.dev_00_01 release with the same error.

What has changed in the current stable release (1.6) and 1.7 dev streams to cause this.
I removed all DartEditor, pub and .dartium folders so not to have any legacy issues, but it still does not work.

I ran pub-upgrade on all apps with no errors - this suggest that my pubspec.lock and pubspec.yaml are OK.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pub upgrade`?. Are all packages upgraded?

Comment: Yes. It says no dependencies changed, but some seems to have upgradable packages - collection 0.9.4 (1.0.0 available),   collection_helpers 0.9.1 (0.9.2 available), quiver 0.18.2 (0.19.0-dev.3 available),  either 0.1.7 (0.1.8 available), matcher 0.10.1+1 (0.11.1 available) and option 0.3.3 (1.1.0 available). Those such as polymer etc are uptodate.

Comment: Seems fine. I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com/new